# Configure multiple instance of mysql 5.6 on centos 7

Tags: mysql, linux, centos7, mysql-5.6

Hi i m trying to install multiple instances of mysql 5.6 on a centos 7 server.
I tried to duplicate the file my.cnf to my2.cnf pointing to a new datadir, i used the mysqld_install_db command to create a new data dir but after that i don't know how to enable the creation of another process with the config of my my2.cnf
can someone help me please?

my purpose will be after to sync each instances with different servers.

Thank you.

Comment: there is a way to specify the location of the .cnf on the mysqld command line. can't remember what it is offhand, but you'd basically have `mysqld --config=my.cnf ; mysqld --config=my2.cnf`, whatever those options happen to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a way to specify the location of the .cnf on the mysqld command line. can't remember what it is offhand, but you'd basically have `mysqld --config=my.cnf ; mysqld --config=my2.cnf`, whatever those options happen to be.
                    – Marc B